# AfNetworking image loading issue

Tags: ios, image, afnetworking-3

I am having a little trouble implementing the AFNetworking 3.0 image loading method. This is the way I am trying to use it. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]] placeholderImage:nil  success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
    self.imageView.image = image;
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to retrieve image");
}];
```

It is giving me compile time error which is:

> No Visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURLRequest:placeHolder:success:failure

Comment: what is the trouble?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I added the error response.

Comment: have you imported some file related to it?

Comment: I found the solution. I didn't  import any file related to this method. So, I just added #import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h" and it is good.

Comment: Great! you found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import this file : `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`.

This includes the method `setImageWithURLRequest:placeHolder:success:failure` method.